# Part number / model for IBM PC 350 keyboard

Tags: ibm-pc, keyboards

what was the part number or model of the original keyboard shipped with [IBM PC 350](https://www.cnet.com/products/ibm-pc-350-6586-dt-pentium-133-mhz-16-mb-1-2-gb/)?

Trying to restore the full set.

Comment: Not sure what they came with but it's a damn fine machine deserving of a Model M, IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Personal Systems Reference IBM PC 1994 to 2000](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/withdrawnbook/dwbook.pdf) (PDF) it appears the default was the Standard 101 keyboard (rubber dome) with optional upgrade to an Enhanced 101 key (Model M) or Enhanced 101 key with TrackPoint II (Model M13) up until the Pentium 60 model, with only the Standard 101 rubber dome after that until it was replaced with the Standard 104 rubber dome on the Pentium 133 models and later.

[image: Snippet from IBM spec sheet.]

IBM Standard 104 Keyboard pictured below.  The 101 Key model appears very similar, minus the windows keys.

[image: IBM Standard 104 Keyboard (rubber dome) pictured with a IBM 300PL.3]